# C# Upload a big file on Azure

Tags: c#, file, azure, upload, blob

I need to do an uploader. All files are stored in Azure cloud. So it's "blob" files.

The uploader is working but only with small files, when the client try to upload a big file (video >50Mb for example), the upload is stopped after like 3 or 4 minutes.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
string connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionStr);
 CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 // Retrieve a reference to a container. 
 string containerName = this.User.Login;
 containerName = containerName.ToLower();
 CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
 //Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
 container.CreateIfNotExists();
 BlobContainerPermissions blobContainerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
 blobContainerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
 container.SetPermissions(blobContainerPermissions);
 // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
 CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("fichiers-" + uploadFile.FileName.ToLower());
 // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
 using (var fileStream = uploadFile.InputStream)
 {
     blockBlob.UploadFromStream(uploadFile.InputStream);
 }
```

Comment: then what is the error?

Comment: "Stopped" is not a useful problem description. It makes answering very hard. What did you do to resolve the problem so far?

Comment: It's not clear if the upload is stopping while it's going to your web server or when it's transferring to Azure blob storage. Can you confirm whether the large uploads are timing out before or after they hit your upload to Azure method?

Comment: It is stopped because I think you are using app service which has request timeout like 3-4 minutes. It stops processing the request if it runs more than 3-4 minutes and you can not see the result and error message in application insights as well. Because you don't get any response and it's not displayed in application insights. You should use PutBlockList and send blocks asynchronously instead of sending 50mb at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can attempt solve this kind of problem, you should investigate the behavior a little more.  One way to do this with Microsoft Azure is to use Fiddler. Make sure your connection to the Azure Storage account uses HTTP, not HTTPS, and simply perform a trace of your HTTP calls. You should see your payloads, and see if you have error messages coming back; you would also be able to infer the retry logic, if any, the size of the payloads and so forth.

Your issue could simply be a form of throttling from Microsoft Azure, in which case you may need to look into a form of retry logic, or break up your payload in smaller chunks.

Comment: I agree that looking at the network traffic might help diagnose the problem, but if this is running out of memory on the Azure server as I suspect then the network traffic isn't going to help solve the problem. BTW, you *can* look at HTTPS traffic with Fiddler; and you can also look at network traffic with F12 tools in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that you ran out of memory: for very large files, buffering them on the server before storing them into blob storage means you'd need to have enough memory on the server to hold the file. A more robust solution would be to upload the file from the browser directly to blob storage, and to upload the file in chunks. I found this article and sample helpful, but I did have to make a few small fixes in the code.

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/